# Python opencv face recognition video not smooth

Tags: python, opencv

I use python opencv create face recognition. The problem is the video not smooth. It alway jerk. So, I use `if count%(10*fps)` to get face regcognize process image after 10 frame not process every frame. It make video smoother but it not show rectangle and text in image. How to fix it?

```
KNOWN_FACES_DIR = 'known_faces'
TOLERANCE = 0.5
FRAME_THICKNESS = 3
FONT_THICKNESS = 2
MODEL = 'hog'  # default: 'hog', other one can be 'cnn' - CUDA accelerated (if available) deep-learning pretrained model

video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
fps = int(video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))

print('Loading known faces...')
known_faces = []
known_names = []

for name in os.listdir(KNOWN_FACES_DIR):

    for filename in os.listdir(f'{KNOWN_FACES_DIR}/{name}'):

        # Load an image
        image = face_recognition.load_image_file(f'{KNOWN_FACES_DIR}/{name}/{filename}')
        encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(image)[0]

        # Append encodings and name
        known_faces.append(encoding)
        known_names.append(name)
        

def check_face(known_faces, known_names):
    
    count = 0
    
    while True:
        
        ret, image = video.read()
        
        if count%(10*fps) == 0:       ########## Process after 10 frame ################
            locations = face_recognition.face_locations(image, model=MODEL)
            encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(image, locations)
        
            for face_encoding, face_location in zip(encodings, locations):
        
                results = face_recognition.compare_faces(known_faces, face_encoding, TOLERANCE)
                match = None
                
                if True in results:  # If at least one is true, get a name of first of found labels
                    match = known_names[results.index(True)]
                    print(f"Match found: {match}")
        
                    # Each location contains positions in order: top, right, bottom, left
                    top_left = (face_location[3], face_location[0])
                    bottom_right = (face_location[1], face_location[2])
            
                    # Get color by name using our fancy function
                    color = [0,255,0]
            
                    # Paint frame
                    cv2.rectangle(image, top_left, bottom_right, color, FRAME_THICKNESS)
            
                    # Now we need smaller, filled grame below for a name
                    # This time we use bottom in both corners - to start from bottom and move 50 pixels down
                    top_left = (face_location[3], face_location[2])
                    bottom_right = (face_location[1], face_location[2] + 22)
            
                    # Paint frame
                    cv2.rectangle(image, top_left, bottom_right, color, cv2.FILLED)
            
                    # Wite a name
                    cv2.putText(image, match, (face_location[3] + 10, face_location[2] + 15), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (200, 200, 200), FONT_THICKNESS)
    
        count+=1                    
    
        
        # Show image
        cv2.imshow("", image)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break


check_face(known_faces, known_names)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make 2 threads:

1. First tread to show and update your image with bounding boxes and text fast
2. The second thread to update the result of neural network and put in to first thread

As example you can use this code and put here the part for detection to th2

```
import cv2
import threading
import time

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)


ret, frame = cap.read()
exit = False
top_lef=(0,0)
bottom_right=(0,0)

def th1():
    global ret, frame, exit,top_lef,bottom_right

    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
    ## here put code to show image and rectangle
    
    cv2.rectangle(frame, top_left, bottom_right, color, cv2.FILLED)
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
        cv2.waitKey(30)

        if exit:
            break

def th2():
    global ret, frame, exit,top_lef,bottom_right
    while True:
    
    ### put here the code to make face recogition


    #top_left, bottom_right =  face prediction result
    
        if cv2.getWindowProperty('frame',cv2.WND_PROP_VISIBLE) < 1:
            exit = True
            break

t1 = threading.Thread(target=th1)
t1.start()
t2 = threading.Thread(target=th2)
t2.start()
```